# to add menu item at wordpress admin side after menu item nmely "setting"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, trying to write a plugin to add one menu item `"Info"` which will further have 2 submenus say entry & link. But i dont know how to do it.
I have read articles on `add_options_page()` & `add_submenu_page()` but I don't get it exactly what to do.
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below function for create menu and sub menu for admin panel:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page() 
{
    add_menu_page("Info", "Info", 0, "info-slug", "infoPageFunction");
    add_submenu_page("info-slug", "Entry", "Entry", 0, "entry-slug", "entryPageFunction");
    add_submenu_page("info-slug", "Link", "Link", 0, "link-slug", "linkPageFunction");
}
function infoPageFunction()
{
    echo "Admin Info Page"; 
}
function entryPageFunction()
{
    echo "Admin Sub menu Entry Page";   
}
function linkPageFunction()
{
    echo "Admin Sub menu Link Page";    
}
```

For beginner,

Refer word press codex for create menu  [Add Menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Refer word press codex for create sub menu  [Add sub menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

Answer (score 0):

For main menu

```
add_menu_page()
```

For sub menu use

```
add_submenu_page()
```

For this function argument you can refer wordpress site.

Comment: I have used it, and after reloading page menu was added as submenu to settings

Comment: Which method you was used ?